# How to get a suggestion through solrTemplate

Tags: java, spring-data-solr

When using solrTemplate, I have no way to get the results in suggest. With `solrj` I can use `getSuggesterResponse()` to get this result.

I debugged it and found that it didn't use `getSuggesterResponse()` to get the suggest.

solrj

```
    HttpSolrClient httpSolrServer = SolrUtil.createSolrServer();
    SolrQuery solrQuery = new SolrQuery();
    solrQuery.set("qt", "/suggest");
    solrQuery.setQuery("mm");
    QueryResponse response = httpSolrServer.query(solrQuery);
    SuggesterResponse suggesterResponse = response.getSuggesterResponse();
    Map<String, List<String>> suggestedTerms = 
    suggesterResponse.getSuggestedTerms();
    List<String> terms = suggestedTerms.get("suggest");
```

solrTemplate:

```
    TermsQuery query = new SimpleTermsQuery();
    query.setRequestHandler("/suggest");
    query.addCriteria(new Criteria().is("mm"));
    TermsPage terms = solrTemplate.queryForTermsPage("core2", query);
```

I checked all the documentation, but I didn't find a way.

Comment: @Query(requestHandler = "/suggest")

 @Spellcheck(dictionaries = {"suggestion"}, count = 5, extendedResults = true)

 SpellcheckedPage<Risk> findByRiskName(String riskName, Pageable page);

I tried Spellcheck again, but still can't.

Answer (score 0):

I think solrTemplate has no native support for suggest.
But you can use solrJ inside of solrTemplate

```
SolrQuery q = new SolrQuery();

q.setRequestHandler("/suggest");
q.setParam("suggest.q", searchTerm);
q.setParam("suggest", "true");
q.setParam("suggest.dictionary", "mySuggester");
q.setParam("suggest.build", "true");

QueryResponse queryResponse = solrTemplate.execute(solrClient -> solrClient.query("collectionName", q));

SuggesterResponse suggesterResponse = queryResponse.getSuggesterResponse();
```